# How do I enable dynamic content in a theme cached with WP Super Cache?

Tags: cache, plugin-wp-supercache

I've been trying to improve my caching strategies in the themes I build, but I'm having trouble understanding how "Enable dynamic caching" works in WP Super Cache. There's very little information on this through searches, and what I have been able to find has been extremely technical, targeted towards one non-cached region, or otherwise not helpful.

So far what I've been able to discern is that there are global, secret, tags that get replaced with the dynamic content when a page loads. What I can't figure out, though, is how to set up *multiple* of these. As far as I'm aware, you can only use `define("DYNAMIC_OUTPUT_BUFFER_TAG", "")` once, otherwise the value will be overwritten by the later declarations.

I'm looking for a guide on how to serve simple dynamic elements to different areas of a page.

For example, if I had the following requirements:

- Display the current time in the header via `current_time("c")`
- Display the current users IP address in the footer via `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`

How can this be achieved while maintaining caching for the rest of the page?

*Related Links:*

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/#faq
- https://odd.blog/2013/10/21/shiny-new-dynamic-content-wp-super-cache/

Comment: I usually try to use ajax requests in place of fragmented caching for situations like this since `admin-ajax.php` bypasses cache. Is that an option for your situation?

Comment: I've heard of this solution as well, but I think this would a bit complicated for my actual use case (in some cases swapping in large blocks of HTML), so ideally, I'd like to know how to do this with PHP. I'll definitely explore using AJAX, though, thanks.

Comment: you can only use define once because it's a PHP constant, not a variable

Comment: Supposedly, the content from the database is variable since plugins can filter it (adding counts, times, ads, translations). Why would you put the onus of caching on the theme, and why focus on just one caching plugin?

Comment: @JoyReynolds yes, it being a constant is why I'm confused about this implementation -- it seems to me that this means you can only have one non-cached region on a page, which is extremely limiting. As for focusing on wp-super-cache, it's just what I'm used to, and it's also the most installed caching plugin, and built by Automattic, who also build WordPress itself. I'm open to other plugins, but I figured this would be the best route.